# gnu-screen: Automatically run script when attach/detach session

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I would like to have bash script run by screen every time when i attach (start.sh) or detach (end.sh) session.

Is there any way to configure screen to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the scripts, then you can do that.  But screen by itself does not have hooks to be called on reattach or detach.  There is no event handler system accessible to the user.

However for detach, you might be able to `exec` commands in on keyboard sequences.  For example, `bind ^D exec ${HOME}/bin/end.sh`; and then have `~/bin/end.sh` do what you need and force a detach on the screen session.  You might also be able to do this with `stuff`.